# Provisioning profile doesn't include signing certificate

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Появились ошибки, уже и обновил сертификаты 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и выбрал автоматическое управление подписью, все равно ошибки остаются, как быть?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуй зайти в настройки xcode и авторизуйся там под своим аккаунтом, xcode должен подтянуть все новые сертификаты и provisions

Comment: зарегин под своим аккаунтом... Обнаружил один момент, серт привязанный в связку ключей пишет, что отозван. Может быть это причиной? И как переподвизать тогда новый? Скрин тоже добавил в вопрос

Comment: Новый нужно просто создать в аккаунте на Apple Developer, а затем дать Xcode переподтянуть его в Preferences.

Answer (score 0):

Выберите Automatically manage signing, а затем в настройках сборки (Build Settings) в разделе Signing -> Provisioning Profile укажите Automatic. Сейчас у вас provisioning profile задаётся вручную и не содержит signing certificate, который автоматически подставляет Xcode при включенном автоматическом управлении подписью.

Иными словами – либо всё на Automatic, т.е. дать Xcode право разруливать весь процесс подписи самостоятельно, либо всё вручную. Смешивание ручного управления и автоматических действий от Xcode чаще всего ведёт к странным проблемам и трудноуловимым багам.

Comment: Дело в том, что у меня в Provisioning Profile указанно Automatic. Скрин приложил к вопросу